# org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize | out of START_OBJECT token;

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, unit-testing

I'm making an unit test for an endpoint which returns an array of objects but there is an error executioning the tests:

```
[ERROR] whenFindByStatus_returnDocuments  Time elapsed: 0.105 s  <<< ERROR!
org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException:
Error while extracting response for type [java.util.List<cl.rdbc.filestransfer.services.vo.DocumentoVo>] and content type [application/json]; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList<cl.rdbc.filestransfer.services.vo.DocumentoVo>` out of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList<cl.rdbc.filestransfer.services.vo.DocumentoVo>` out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]
        at cl.rdbc.filestransfer.controllers.ControllerLayerTests.whenFindByStatus_returnDocuments(ControllerLayerTests.java:172)
Caused by: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException:
JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList<cl.rdbc.filestransfer.services.vo.DocumentoVo>` out of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList<cl.rdbc.filestransfer.services.vo.DocumentoVo>` out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]
        at cl.rdbc.filestransfer.controllers.ControllerLayerTests.whenFindByStatus_returnDocuments(ControllerLayerTests.java:172)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException:
Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList<cl.rdbc.filestransfer.services.vo.DocumentoVo>` out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]
        at cl.rdbc.filestransfer.controllers.ControllerLayerTests.whenFindByStatus_returnDocuments(ControllerLayerTests.java:172)
```

the error line is the one where is trying to consume the endpoint with *exchange()*:

```
@Test
    void whenFindByStatus_returnDocuments() throws JsonProcessingException {
        String estado = "Autorizado";
        DocumentoVo[] expectedDocs = TestUtils.generateDocumentVoArray();
        when(documentService.findDocumentByEstado(estado)).thenReturn(Arrays.asList(expectedDocs));
        
        System.out.println(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(expectedDocs));

        Map<String, Object> uriVariables = new HashMap<>();
        uriVariables.put("status", estado);
        UriComponents uriBuilder = UriComponentsBuilder.newInstance().scheme("http").host("localhost").port(port)
                .path("/documents/find-by-status/{status}").buildAndExpand(uriVariables);
        System.out.println(uriBuilder.toString());

        ResponseEntity<List<DocumentoVo>> actualDocs = restTemplate.exchange(uriBuilder.toUri(), HttpMethod.GET, null,
                new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<DocumentoVo>>() {
                });

        assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK, actualDocs.getStatusCode());
    }
```

This is the endpoint:

```
@GetMapping("/documents/find-by-status/{status}")
    public List<DocumentoVo> retievePendingDocuments(@PathVariable(name = "status") String estado) {
        
        log.debug("Buscando documentos con estado: {}", estado);
        return service.findDocumentByEstado(estado);
    }
```

..and the service delegated by the controller:

```
public List<DocumentoVo> findDocumentByEstado(String estado) {
        EstadoDocumentoVo estadoDocVo = estadoDocService.findByDescription(estado);
        EstadoDocumento estadoDoc = new EstadoDocumento();
        estadoDoc.setIdEstado(estadoDocVo.getId());
        estadoDoc.setDescEstado(estadoDocVo.getDescripcion());

        List<Documento> documentosPendientes = documentsRepo.findByStatus(estadoDocVo.getId());
        List<DocumentoVo> documentosPendientesVo = new ArrayList<>();
        Iterator<Documento> docsIterator = documentosPendientes.iterator();
        while (docsIterator.hasNext()){
            Documento doc = docsIterator.next();
            DocumentoVo docTemp = VoBuilderFactory.getDocumentoVoBuilder(doc).build();
            documentosPendientesVo.add(docTemp);
        }
        return documentosPendientesVo;
    }
```

And here's the object it's trying to map:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class DocumentoVo implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6799399135160981458L;
    private Long id;
    private String nomDocumentoSti;
    private String nomDocumentoUsuario;
    private Date fechaCreacion;
    private String hashDocumento;
    private TipoDocumentoVo tipoDocumento;
    private EstadoDocumentoVo estadoDocumento;
    private UsuarioVo usuario;
    private String rutaCloudDocumento;
    private String casillaOrigen;
    private String casillaDestino;
    private long cantidadRegistros;
    private BigInteger montoTotalDocumento;
    private InstitucionVo institucionDestino;

}
```

oh! and this is the json printed *expectedDocs*:

```
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "nomDocumentoSti":"test.csv",
      "nomDocumentoUsuario":null,
      "fechaCreacion":null,
      "hashDocumento":null,
      "tipoDocumento":null,
      "estadoDocumento":null,
      "usuario":{
         "id":1,
         "userName":"nombre Usuario",
         "habilitado":false,
         "password":null,
         "institucion":null
      },
      "rutaCloudDocumento":null,
      "casillaOrigen":"casillaOrigen1",
      "casillaDestino":"casillaDestino1",
      "cantidadRegistros":0,
      "montoTotalDocumento":null,
      "institucionDestino":null
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "nomDocumentoSti":"test.csv",
      "nomDocumentoUsuario":null,
      "fechaCreacion":null,
      "hashDocumento":null,
      "tipoDocumento":null,
      "estadoDocumento":null,
      "usuario":{
         "id":1,
         "userName":"nombre Usuario",
         "habilitado":false,
         "password":null,
         "institucion":null
      },
      "rutaCloudDocumento":null,
      "casillaOrigen":"casillaOrigen2",
      "casillaDestino":"casillaDestino2",
      "cantidadRegistros":0,
      "montoTotalDocumento":null,
      "institucionDestino":null
   },
   {
      "id":1,
      "nomDocumentoSti":"test.csv",
      "nomDocumentoUsuario":null,
      "fechaCreacion":null,
      "hashDocumento":null,
      "tipoDocumento":null,
      "estadoDocumento":null,
      "usuario":{
         "id":1,
         "userName":"nombre Usuario",
         "habilitado":false,
         "password":null,
         "institucion":null
      },
      "rutaCloudDocumento":null,
      "casillaOrigen":"casillaOrigen3",
      "casillaDestino":"casillaDestino3",
      "cantidadRegistros":0,
      "montoTotalDocumento":null,
      "institucionDestino":null
   }
]
```

I already tried using DocumentoVo[] instead but the same error arises. It's like if Jackson has problems deserializing lists. Can you spot any errors?

Comment: can you try on the rest template call something like this ` ResponseEntity<DocumentoVo[]> actualDocs = restTemplate.exchange(uriBuilder.toUri(), HttpMethod.GET, null,
                new ParameterizedTypeReference<DocumentoVo[].class>() {
                });`

Comment: Hernandez if still does not work I would change the rest template call to the one provided in this example (on the subsection "Using arrays") https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-template-list . RestTemplate can be a nightmare...

Comment: Using arrays was my first attempt and the same error persists. The problem is something else...

Comment: did you find the solution @Edgar?  you can post your own answer to help others

Comment: @Carlos nope, I commented the test and posponed its solution